# Pro*C compilation on RHEL 8, problem in including math.h

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-pro-c, rhel8

I've a simple C code which I'm trying to compile on RHEL 8 machine wherein Oracle 19c client is installed.
Here's the program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
/* #include <math.h> */
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  printf("\nHey!!\n");
}
```

This code gets compiled well with gcc as well as proc (Pro*C pre-compiler) commands.

But once I uncomment **#include <math.h>**, a lot of syntax errors are reported when proc command is run.

Command that I'm running is:

```
proc iname=test.c oname=test.cp \
                          include=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/include/ \
                          include=. \
                          userid=<db connection string> \
                          sqlcheck=full \
                          define=ORACLE_PRECOMPILE \
                          code=ansi_c \
                          char_map=string \
                          dbms=v8 \
                          lines=yes \
                          ltype=long \
                          oraca=yes \
                          parse=full \
                          select_error=yes \
                          unsafe_null=yes
```

Syntax errors reported are (copying couple of errors only):

```
Syntax error at line 62, column 1, file /usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:
Error at line 62, column 1 in file /usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h
__MATHCALL_VEC (cos,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "extern" when expecting one of the following
:

   ; , = ( [
The symbol ";" was substituted for "extern" to continue.

Syntax error at line 64, column 1, file /usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:
Error at line 64, column 1 in file /usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h
__MATHCALL_VEC (sin,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "extern" when expecting one of the following
:

   ; , = ( [
The symbol ";" was substituted for "extern" to continue.
```

This same command works well when **#include <math.h>** is commented.

Also, this command works fine on old RHEL 6 machine even when math.h is included (*of course after changing include path to RHEL 6 machine's include directory*).

I tried searching for solution of this problem on internet but couldn't find any helpful article.

OS version:

```
cat os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.4 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.4"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.4 (Ootpa)"
```

Any help on this will be very useful.

Comment: you can [edit] your question to add that info.

Comment: Apparently the header file "math.h" contains code that "proc" does not understand. Investigate this further.

Comment: This seems to be a [known issue](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2709148_1.html) with Pro*C on RHEL 8.  (Note: it appears that an Oracle support subscription is required to access the details behind that link.)

Comment: Ooof.  Over a year, and Oracle still doesn't support RHEL 8?!?!  RHEL 8 was released almost three years ago.

Comment: Thanks John. 4 solutions are mentioned in the link you referred, I tried one I found least intrusive and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the dame issue and simply added the line

define=_MATH_H

to the pcscfg.cfg located in the $ORACLE_HOME/precomp/admin directory which fixed the issue for me.